# is possible to pass variable in a query SQL statement?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm wanting to know if it's possible to pass a variable into an SQL statement for a query, rather than making 12 different queries which would also have me making 12 different forms (1 for each query). The table name to update depends on the column "what_table" in a table named "weekinfo".

currently the SQL statement is:

```
SELECT wk1_info.ID, wk1_info.Player_Fname, wk1_info.Player_Lname, wk1_info.email, wk1_info.postion
FROM wk1_info
WHERE (((wk1_info.postion) Like 0));
```

is it possible to declare the table this way, or would I have to make the extra queries and forms? If it is possible could I pointed in the right direction?

Comment: Look into using a parameter in a query, [see here](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/use-parameters-in-queries-forms-and-reports-8209eb5c-1589-42e2-9b20-4181f4c7a356).

Comment: This is a non-normalized design. You should store similar data in the same table. You can't use table names as parameters. Instead, adjust your data so you can filter for week

Comment: the reasoning for this is that I have a main table that holds all the information from 12 other tables. The query selects only columns in a specific table (where the table name = "what_table" from the table "weekinfo") and only updates that table

Answer (score 0):

No. Table and field names cannot be passed as parameters.

What you can do is to write the full SQL from a template string replacing tokens for table and/or fields names with those you need. Then run/execute the finished SQL string.